# Moving to next field when pressing Next

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've been trying to do a generic validation mechanism for `EntryElement`s using MonoTouch.Dialogs and I thought that the delegate `ShouldReturn` could help me to do that but it looks that I was wrong.

If I create a simple `EntryElement` like this:

```cs
new RootElement {
    new Section {
        new EntryElement(string.Empty, string.Empty, null),
        new EntryElement(string.Empty, string.Empty, null)
    }
}
```

When I test it and entering text in the first entry element and press next everything works as expected and we move to the next entry element field.

Well, as soon as I set the first entry element to something like this:

```cs
var entry = new EntryElement(string.Empty, string.Empty, null);
entry.ShouldReturn += () => true;
```

The "Next" functionality in the input keyboard doesn't work.

Am I missing something or I did understand wrongly the workings of EntryElement.ShouldReturn?

Answer (score 0):

The `EntryElement.SouldReturn` event is just a proxy for the underlying `UITextField.ShouldReturn` event. Even if `EntryElement` lacks documentation for `ShouldReturn`, you can refer to [UITextField doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a)

To me, it looks like you should be able to use `ShouldReturn` for validation, but if you want the Next button to keep working, I'd return false.

```cs
entry.ShouldReturn += () => {
    //Validate
    return false;
}
```